# PHP Regex: 127.0.0.1 (and check port)

Tags: php, regex

I have a form, which has a field for an IP-address.
And I want to check if the IP is 127.0.0.1, because I'm going to ping the IP.
Obviously pinging 127.0.0.1 will ping the localhost.

In order to prevent this, I want to use a preg_match which should check for this:
- 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.1 which includes a port (eg. 127.0.0.1:80)

Comment: What version of PHP? You can use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) PHP >= v5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^127\.0{1,3}\.0{1,3}\.0{,2}1(:[0-9]+)?$
```

should do the trick... if I can **assume** you're using PHP's [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (or [similar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)) for the task.

Comment: Updated to account for leading zeros, per @jperovic's response.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $pattern = "/^127\.0{0,3}\.0{0,3}.0{0,2}1(:\d+)?$/";
    $string = "127.0.0.1:8080";

    if ( preg_match($pattern, $string)){
        echo 'is a match';
    }else{
        echo 'is not a match';
    }
?>
```

This should work. Please note that you have to take into account leading zeros...

Comment: Good call on the leading zeros. +1

Answer (score 0):

`127\.0\.0\.1(?:\:[0-9]+)?`

Looks for 127.0.0.1 with colon followed by 1 or more numbers.

Comment: Thanks, please next time include the full regex including delimiter. Also, port should be limited to 5 chars.

Comment: @ArtaexMedia - Do you have any idea how rude these comments make you sound?

Comment: @ArtaexMedia - Next time, please demonstrate to us that you're at least willing to **try** to solve the problem yourself before prompting the community. We're friendly, and we don't bite - as long as you're not abusive.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one
`/(127\.0\.0\.1\:.+?\d{1,5})|(127\.0\.0\.1)/`